# Java generics: Calling generic Method "...is not applicable for the arguments..."

Tags: java, class, generics, methods

I have 2 HashMaps with `<Integer, "sometype">`. So the "sometype" may differ and therefore i tried to make it generic. In this case my two varaibles are as follows

```
private HashMap<Integer, UI_FieldPV> values_map = new HashMap<Integer, UI_FieldPV>();
private HashMap<Integer, JComponent> input_map = new HashMap<Integer, JComponent>();
```

The first call of the method is fine:

```
this.input_map = MapOperations.<JComponent> rearrengeHashMapIdx(this.input_map);
```

the second call passes a HashMap with `<Integer, CustomClass>`

```
this.values_map = MapOperations.<UI_FieldPV>rearrengeHashMapIdx(this.input_map);
```

which gives me the following error:

> The parameterized method `<UI_FieldPV>rearrengeHashMapIdx(HashMap<Integer,UI_FieldPV>)` of type `UI.MapOperations` is not applicable for the arguments `(HashMap<Integer,JComponent>)`

Coding of the class which contains the generic method (btw: I tried to create a generic method within the calling class but it didnÄt work. Do i have to create a embedded class in order to make generic method paramaters work?)

```
private static class MapOperations<T> {
    public static <T> HashMap<Integer, T> rearrengeHashMapIdx(HashMap<Integer, T> source) {

        HashMap<Integer, T> temp = new HashMap<Integer, T>();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < 81; i++) {
            Integer rowNum = (i / 3) % 3;
            Integer block = i / 9;
            Integer delta = (rowNum - block);
            Integer newIdx = i + (delta * 6);
            temp.put(i, source.get(newIdx));
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

So what am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: The type argument for the generic method is not necessary, its inferred from the arguments passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler error is clear enough. The first invocation of method:

```
this.input_map = MapOperations.<JComponent>rearrengeHashMapIdx(this.input_map);
```

would return a `HashMap<Integer, JComponent>`, as you have given the explicit type parameter (well, that is not really needed here. The type `T` will anyways be inferred from the type of `HashMap` you are passing). That is fine, as you have declared your `input_map` to be of that type only.

Then you are passing `input_map` as argument to the next method invocation:

```
this.values_map = MapOperations.<UI_FieldPV>rearrengeHashMapIdx(this.input_map);
```

Now, as per the declaration of the method, the argument to the method should be of type `HashMap<Integer, T>`. In the second method invocation, the type parameter `T` is inferred as `UI_FieldPV`. So, the method expects a `HashMap<Integer, UI_FieldPV>`, but you are passing a `HashMap<Integer, JComponent>`. Of course the method invocation would fail, as both the maps are incompatible.

Perhaps, in the second invocation, you meant to pass `values_map` as argument. So this would work fine:

```
this.values_map = MapOperations.<UI_FieldPV>rearrengeHashMapIdx(this.values_map);
```

Note that the type parameter `T` used in the method is unrelated to the type parameter `T` used with the class declaration, although that doesn't make any difference here. But just FYI.

Comment: Oh... my fault. Didn't see that obvious one.
I changed it to
`(HashMap<Integer, UI_FieldPV>) this.rearrengeHashMapIdx(this.values_map);`

Now i get same error
`(The method put(Integer, capture#4-of ?) in the type HashMap<Integer,capture#4-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Integer, capture#5-of ?))`

but now on this line of code (in the method posted in my original post):
`temp.put(i, source.get(newIdx));`
UI_FieldPV class extends JPanel by the way.

Comment: Okay i dont know why but after saving, closing and restarting eclipse the error disappeared.....

Problem solved! Ty

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand, ¿you put "input_map" intentionally?:

```
this.values_map = MapOperations.<UI_FieldPV>rearrengeHashMapIdx(this.input_map);
```

Maybe you need something like:

```
this.values_map = MapOperations.<UI_FieldPV>rearrengeHashMapIdx(this.values_map);
```

Comment: thanks for your help! I've not seen this somehow stupid mistake. However it only "shifted" the problem (see the answer to the second post)